# Grid not working after reloading on alternate calls

Tags: jqgrid

```
$("#tableVisualization").jqGrid('GridUnload');

$("#tableVisualization").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    mtype: 'GET', 
    colNames: this.GetGridColumnNames(),
    colModel: this.GetGridColumnModel(),
    height: "100%", 
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: true,
    sortname: 'monthID', 
    sortorder: "desc", 
    rowList: [6, 12], 
    rowNum: 12,
    pager: $('#pager3'), 
    viewrecords: true, 
    recordpos: "left", 
    caption: "Table" 
});

//local data array used for example
var data = this.GetGridData();

//FUNCTION CALL
//populate grid with data
$("#tableVisualization").jqGrid("addRowData", "month", data);

$("#tableVisualization").trigger("reloadGrid"); 

$("#tableVisualization").setGridWidth(1040, true);
```

Above code works fine.

However if I assign `$("#tableVisualization")` to a variable and use the variable in the above code it does not work.

`//var grid = $("#tableVisualization")`;

It works every alternate call.

For example if the whole code was inside a javascript method called `LoadGrid()`, then the first call to the method works, second call does not, third works, fourth does not and so on.

I have seen during debugging, when it reached "`grid.jqGrid('GridUnload')`" on the even calls, the grid is completely removed(im not sure if the html table is removed or not) and it is not created during `"$("#tableVisualization").jqGrid({.....});"`.

Can anyone please explain me the reason for this behaviour.

I can make the scenario work because now I am not using a local variable but I would like to know why it does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see exactly what is going on within the grid's `GridUnload` method in [`grid.custom.js`](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.custom.js):

```
GridUnload : function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        if ( !this.grid ) {return;}
        var defgrid = {id: $(this).attr('id'),cl: $(this).attr('class')};
        if (this.p.pager) {
            $(this.p.pager).empty().removeClass("ui-state-default ui-jqgrid-pager corner-bottom");
        }
        var newtable = document.createElement('table');
        $(newtable).attr({id:defgrid.id});
        newtable.className = defgrid.cl;
        var gid = $.jgrid.jqID(this.id);
        $(newtable).removeClass("ui-jqgrid-btable");
        if( $(this.p.pager).parents("#gbox_"+gid).length === 1 ) {
            $(newtable).insertBefore("#gbox_"+gid).show();
            $(this.p.pager).insertBefore("#gbox_"+gid);
        } else {
            $(newtable).insertBefore("#gbox_"+gid).show();
        }
        $("#gbox_"+gid).remove();
    });
},
```

The key points to understand are:

- A new `table` element is inserted with the same DOM `id` as the old table. We can see it created in the call to `document.createElement('table')` and inserted in one of the calls to `insertBefore`.
- The existing jqGrid DOM is removed in the call to `$("#gbox_"+gid).remove()`. Since the old table element is contained within the `gbox`, it is removed as well.

After the call to `GridUnload`, the DOM element that it refers to no longer exists on the page, so any code that references the element is ineffective.

Does that help?

Comment: So, this means the existing DOM element will be removed and a new table element with the same id will be created on calling GridUnload. In that case, when the code reached "$("#tableVisualization").jqGrid({.....});", shouldnt it create a new jqgrid like a fresh new one within the new table element.

Comment: Yes, but if you already have `grid` assigned and then you say `grid.jqGrid({...})` after calling `GridUnload` that is where you will run into trouble.

Comment: Oh. I get it clearly now. So, that was a silly assignment mistake from me. I should have assigned it after the grid creation part, since the unload would remove the existing bindings. oops. :). thank you so much Justin.